# showing total up and down vote counts

Tags: support, privileges

how can I see the total up and down vote counts?

any example q?

Comment: Also, check out http://superuser.com/privileges (you can get there by clicking your rep number on the top-bar of the main site) - most of the privileges include some sort of instructions on their usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just click right on the number:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you have 1k rep just click the score itself to see the up and down breakdown.